# What are the plural equivalents of Messrs for Ms, Miss & Mrs?

Tags: abbreviations, titles, irregular-plurals, honorifics, forms-of-address

Mr. smith and Mr. Jones can be expressed as Messrs. Smith and Jones.

How can Ms. Smith and Ms. Jones, or Miss Smith and Miss Jones, or Mrs. Smith and Mrs. Jones respectively be so consolidated?